# Best way to store an array of bitmasked values in a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a bitmask value to store a list of possible people in a row (1=John, 2=Paul, 4=George, 8=Ringo, 16=Pete, etc.) and that's working just fine, but in a certain situation I need to store this value for each day of the week.

I can easily do it by creating columns for each day (peopleSun, peopleMon, peopleTue, etc.) since while the number of people could change, the number of days in a week won't. But it feels so... dirty, like I should be more efficient with it somehow.

I'm using it in connection with PHP, and so I realize I could create an array and encode it using serialize(), but that feels like it makes the database less accessible in the future.

Is there a better way of doing this, or should I just hardwire seven different columns and stop worrying about making my database ready to handle... eight days a week? (ugh, sorry I didn't plan for that, it was just too good to pass up)

Comment: There are also options like JSON data types that allow for dynamic data to be placed into a single column and possibly indexed.

Comment: Thanks for this. I figured out a more natural solution (below) but enjoyed learning about the JSON option... If it helps anybody finding this question in the future, JSON data types were introduced in MySQL 5.7 (and aren't supported in older versions of phpMyAdmin, like the 4.0 I was running).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I wasn't thinking with <strike>portals</strike> relational databases.

I created a second table with columns "people", "day" (1=Sun, 2=Mon, etc), and "recordID" (which is tied to the id of the row in the other table.

Sometimes you just need to let these things simmer for a weekend, I guess...